# MYSQL command entered but I don't understand response

Tags: mysql, syntax, response

I am using MySQL 5.5 and within the MySQL console I enter:

```
mysql>DROP USER 'user@222.222.0.23'
```

and the console then displays

```
mysql>DROP USER 'user@222.222.0.23'
     ->
```

I have no idea what I am suppose to do with this.  Hitting enter just results in

```
mysql>DROP USER 'user@222.222.0.23'
     ->
     ->
```

Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is not finished (with hitting enter) and waits for further input.

Finish the statement with a `;` and hit enter again.

Comment: I take it this is how the console accepts multiple lines.  Thanks for the info!

Comment: @AndroidAddict: This is not related to the "console".  This is how the SQL syntax is defined: a statement has to be terminated with a `;`